# define close event for kendo window when creating from DIV

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I know this is an obscure way to define a Kendo Window, but it's the way we are doing it in our application and it works fine for the most part. I am struggling with the syntax of capturing the Close event when the user closes the window. I have the following which is working for all other intents and purposes:

```
$("<div id=\"" + windowName + "\" />").appendTo(document.body).kendoWindow({
                draggable: true, resizable: true, width: width, height: height,
                scrollable: false, modal: false, actions: ["Close"]
});
```

How do I capture the Close event in order to fire off another function? I have tried adding

```
$("<div id=\"" + windowName + "\" />").appendTo(document.body).kendoWindow({
                draggable: true, resizable: true, width: width, height: height,
                scrollable: false, modal: false, actions: ["Close"], Close:"noteClose",
});
```

in several variations, including adding () after noteClose and also putting "close:" as I saw this in another method of defining a window.

Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

UPDATE: @OnaBai provided a perfect solution to my problem. Also please see OnaBai's answer for the syntax for passing arguments to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions:

1. The name of the event is not `Close` but `close`.
2. The handler needs to be a function.

So it should be:

```
$("<div id=\"" + windowName + "\" />").appendTo(document.body).kendoWindow({
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    scrollable: false,
    modal: false,
    actions: ["Close"],
    close:noteClose
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want to pass some argument to `noteClose` then you need to do:

```
$("<div id=\"" + windowName + "\" />").appendTo(document.body).kendoWindow({
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    scrollable: false,
    modal: false,
    actions: ["Close"],
    close: function() {
        noteClose(parameterVariable);
    }
});
```

Comment: Apologies for another question but how do I pass parameters to the noteClose function using this method? I tried (parameterVariable) which doesnt produce syntactical errors but it then seems the window isnt created in the DOM.

Comment: If you say noteClose(parameterVariable) you are asking to execute it as soon as the window is created and the result is expected to be a function executed when you close. Please, as far as possible do not use comments for new questions since it is less likely than other people read your question and so you decrement your chances of getting the response.

Comment: Point taken, will amend my first post.

Comment: Thanks again for the edit, will amend my first post again for clarity

Comment: No, you did not take the point, what I meant is submit a new question since most people only check for new questions ;-) Anyhow, I know the answer so ...

Comment: Ah fair enough, I was under the impression a notification was sent to people who had contributed to a thread, when it was edited(it might be I don't know) and that people tended to take note of them. Either way, my problem is fixed and I'll keep your advice in mind for the future

Comment: AFAIK it only goes to those that you preceded with '@' and the original poster / answerer